# Cross browser margin issue on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi I have a wordpress theme installed on my website, http://www.my-cv.info, the problem i am having i with the spacing around the edge, in firefox there is a natural space between the edge of the page and the login box on the right.  however in Google the login box runs off of the page.  Originally the page background was white and so it didn't notice until i added a couloured background.  i have looked through the css and made multiple changes, but nothing seems to make a difference.

Thanks

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in your CSS:

```
#home-page-layout_c1_col-1-4_2 form td input[type=text], #home-page-layout_c1_col-1-4_2 form td input[type=password] { 
     width: 110px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, that moved the the username input field but didn't make any difference to the password input field.  Is there a way to add a margin to the whole section, i did try margin and padding, but padding just extends the white area of the website.